# How to distinguish Autodesk Construction Cloud and BIM 360 hubs?

Tags: autodesk-bim360

When getting the list of hubs, I'd like to know how to distinguish a hub from Autodesk Construction Cloud and a hub from Autodesk BIM 360.

For now, I'm using https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs, which retrieves both ACC and BIM 360 hubs. I know that there's the data -> attributes -> extension -> type, but in both cases I receive "hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account"

When getting the list of project using https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/:hub_id/projects, there's data -> attributes -> extension -> data -> projectType which is either ACC or BIM360, which is good. But I'd like to have this information when getting the hubs too. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way either from the hub payload, as far as I could see there is no data that indicate platform ACC/BIM360 type.

However you can detect that from a project, if you fetch a project payload you can use `project.attributes.extension.data.projectType` which is either `ACC` or `BIM360`.

Answer (score 0):

Data Management is a general API. e.g. you use DM APIs to manage your models and data in your own buckets. BIM360 or ACC or Fusion360 etc the platform that manages models or data for end users, in a format of more user-orientated structure like hub>>project>>folder>>item>>version, etc. All these fall into Data Management. BIM 360 API will be more specific in the context of BIM360. e.g. Admin API (like what you are using), Issue API, RFI API, Cost API, Model Coordination API, etc.